# generalizing 'using' in a functional way

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

I've been going through my c# code and trying to convert the majority of it to be more functional.

How do you convert this **using** expression into a more functional-style pattern?

```
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(settingsFolder, settingsFilename)))
    using (var writer = new someClass(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(settings);
    }
```

I'm trying to use this functional pattern (replacing **using** with this **Disposable):**

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static TResult Using<TDisposable, TResult>(
        Func<TDisposable> factory,
        Func<TDisposable, TResult> map)
        where TDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        using (var disposable = factory())
        {
            return map(disposable);
        }
    }
}
```

**Will this pattern not work since the class File is static and sealed?**

Comment: How do you intend to use it?

Comment: You can't pass a static class in as a parameter. You will need to wrap it in a factory class if you want to use this. TBH, I'm not clear why you would want to re-invent this perfectly functional wheel.

Comment: The main problem is that your Using has a return value. Remove it and it should be more easy to use it. There is no problem in the fact that `File.Open` is a static method.

Comment: What do you mean by _more functional_? Looks like you are making a wrapper for using, while using is already 'functional' and 'clean' enough to use.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the solution to a non-existant problem. Think about maintainability. `using()` is a well-understood pattern which each and every .NET developer knows about.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing this, this only convolutes things. Just a tip - if you want to go all out functional programming on .NET, take a look at F#.

Comment: `using` mutates by definition (a no-op `Dispose()` might not mutate, but even then the point is still to give it an opportunity to mutate the object so that it becomes "disposed"). It doesn't really fit in with functional style directly. Sometimes it does indirectly such as how Linq uses a functional style with the enumerables it acts on and returns but enumerating them is mutating enumerators behind the scenes, but that enumerating is not functional even if producing the enumerable is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does work. I am not sure why you would want to do this, but `File` being static doesn't prevent you in any way to do this. The `Func` expects a factory delegate, not a class that can be instantiated.

This code should work for you:

```
Disposable.Using
    ( () => Disposable.Using
                ( () => File.OpenWrite(path)
                , stream => new someClass(stream)
                )
    , writer => { writer.Write(settings); return true; }
    );
```

There is a problem with disposing though, since the inner `using` will already dispose. If possible, you should dispose the `stream` in your `someClass`. If not possible, just use `using`.

The `return true` is solely there for the reason that the `Func` expects a return type. An `Action` would be better fitting in this scenario.

Comment: +1, but formatting is... exotic. I can hardly tell what's going on here. Yet another reason to stick to vanilla `using()`.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you very much for this response, but im just wondering if the editor screwed up the formatting